# How to select large result set from Google BigQuery using .net api client library without pagination

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to select the large result set (~200K) from Google BigQuery using .net client library.

I able to get only ~4K rows at single shot (request & response), Google BigQuery offers **PageToken** to get next set of results. I am able to select all the rows from big query through multiple request to Google Bigquery (~50 Request & Response).

**My Question:** If there is possibility to select large result set in single response? if yes kindly share your code (even JAVA code also is fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to run a query and select a large response in a single shot. You can either paginate the results, or if you can create a job to export to files, then use the files generated in your app. Exporting is free.

Step to run a large query and export results to files stored on GCS:

1) Set allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. You must also specify a destination table with the allowLargeResults flag.

Example:

```
"configuration": 
  {
    "query": 
    {
      "allowLargeResults": true,
      "query": "select uid from [project:dataset.table]"
      "destinationTable": [project:dataset.table]

    }
  }
```

2) Now your data is in a destination table you set. You need to create a new job, and set the [export property](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.extract) to be able to [export the table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery) to file(s). Exporting is free, but you need to have Google Cloud Storage activated to put the resulting files there.

3) In the end you download your large files from GCS.